# Stratified Sampling in a data set with outliers

Tags: distributions, sampling, outliers

Can stratified sampling be used to deal with the outliers that a data set might have? For the data set that I have, when trying to fit a statistical distribution and calculate a Value at Risk by using the Loss Distribution Approach, I find that the outliers( in my case defined based on the 3 standard deviation rule ) distort quite a lot the VAR values and the summary statistics. I read that in statistics one would eliminate the outliers but in this case if eliminated, we loose valuable information. Thus, I was wondering if stratified sampling could be used to deal with these outliers rather then eliminating them to make them more representative for the whole data set.

---

For example, if I get k outliers for my data based on the 3 standard deviation method which I mentioned, I was thinking that I could get k samples from the stratified sampling method and replace the outliers with these new observations. The observations would result from separating the data set into k stratums and replacing the k outliers by the mean of each stratum. In this manner, instead of getting rid of them I could make the data set more representative and when fitting for example a GPD I could get a more realistic VaR value.

Comment: Could you indicate how you think stratified sampling might be applied?

Comment: Do you not plan to use the entire dataset you have?  By sampling (stratified or not) you'd probably be throwing away more information than if you just kept the outliers in the dataset and proceeded as usual.  Otherwise, you'd be throwing away observations that are available to you just to handle this problem.  If you wanted to proceed in a manner similar to the one you've described, you could treat all the outliers as "missing" and then use multiple imputation to impute the values.  I wouldn't recommend this though.  In a large dataset you should have a fair number of "valid" outliers.

Comment: Yes I plan to use the entire data set! I understand the point of view and I agree! I was just looking to understand if there is a way in which one could handle these outlier events (black swans) without removing them such that when modeling the severity distribution I can reach to a more realistic capital charge. I suppose modeling the outliers by a different distribution would be a more robust method ? Thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: @Andreea, Yes.  In this situation, I'd recommend stratifying into dollar maybe three groups (small, medium, and large observations) and you can define your cut-points based on your observed data.  Within each stratum, you could create a separate model.